# Yii2 Date format

Tags: yii2, date-formatting

I am facing a problem with daysuffix of date in php date format. I'm not getting the desired result with php:l dS F Y or php:l jS F Y

I am using the following code in DetailView widget.

```
[
    'label' => 'Institution Date',
    'value' => $model->INSTITUTIONDATE,
    'format' => ['date','php:l dS F Y'],
    'valueColOptions' => ['style'=>'width:30%']
],
```

Please help.

Comment: what would be getting result ?

Comment: show stored date in db.